# Connection terminated for basic Postgres and MassiveJS

Tags: sql, postgresql, massive, massivejs

I am trying to connect to my database, but I am running into some errors. I am pretty new to all this, so sorry if I'm not being clear. I am able to use pgAdmin to run queries to my database, but I can't seem to get it working here.

Here is my error:

```
/Users/patrickholley/Desktop/Dockbox/Dev-Mtn/w6/d3/massive-demo/node_modules/deasync/index.js:46
                            throw err;
                            ^

Error: Connection terminated
at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/patrickholley/Desktop/Dockbox/Dev-Mtn/w6/d3/massive-demo/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:183:17)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:290:19)
at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
at Connection.emit (events.js:185:7)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/patrickholley/Desktop/Dockbox/Dev-Mtn/w6/d3/massive-demo/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:66:10)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at TCP._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:501:12)
at Function.module.exports.loopWhile (/Users/patrickholley/Desktop/Dockbox/Dev-Mtn/w6/d3/massive-demo/node_modules/deasync/index.js:72:22)
at Object.connectSync (/Users/patrickholley/Desktop/Dockbox/Dev-Mtn/w6/d3/massive-demo/node_modules/deasync/index.js:44:19)
```

And here is my server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var massive = require('massive');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = 3000;

var conn = massive.connectSync({
  connectionString : "postgres://postgres@localhost/massive_demo"
});

app.set('db', conn);
var db = app.get('db');

app.get('/incidents', function(req, res) {
  console.log('POST sighting');
});

app.post('/incidents', function(req, res) {
  console.log('POST sighting');
});

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Started server on port", port);
});
```

Don't really know what else to say; I'll do my best to clarify anywhere it's unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out my issue; apparently changing the port in Postgres affected my ability to connect? Not sure why, but changing it back to the default 5432 worked.

Comment: Your connection string does not specify a port that Postgres is listening on so Massive assumes the default. If you want to use a nonstandard port you have to include it: `postgres://postgres@localhost:5433/massive_demo`.